# @Component vs. @NgComponent Dart.Angular

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Can anybody explain to me the difference between 
@Component and @NgComponent. 
Following [Angular.Dart tutorial](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/05-ch03-component.html) which uses @Component I was wondering what is @NgComponent for.

I'm more and more confused as I'm going deeper in Dart space:-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@NgComponent is a legacy terminology for @Component.

GitHub AngularDart Repo:
https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/commit/f055ab6f7c4fadfdbb6a46d8bc547b304586d95c